# Lucene select all query

Tags: syntax, lucene

Im using 3.6.2 lucene and I try to write query which will select all docs.
Here's some of my code:

```
searchString = "content:*";
query = parser.parse(QueryParser.escape(searchString));
indexSearcher.search(query, null, collector);
```

But this request returns only about 25% of docs, I cant get why and how to make such query.

**UPDATE**

`*:*` also didn't select all docs, but replacing query with `new MatchAllDocsQuery()` helped, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`MatchAllDocsQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html). It's string representation is `*:*`.